# How do I get image dimensions from a Base64 Image in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, validation, image-processing

I would like to validate an image on the client-side, checking the dimensions against predefined criteria.

Answer (score 0):

This should help you understand how this can be done.

```js
var img = new Image(); 

var base64Image = 'data:image/png;base64,iVBORw0KGgoAAAANSUhEUgAAABAAAAAQBAMAAADt3eJSAAAAJ1BMVEUAAACAgIDo6Ojq6urt7e3v7+/x8fH09PT29vb4+Pj6+vr9/f3///8nK8D7AAAAAXRSTlMAQObYZgAAAFZJREFUCB0FwcERAUEUBcCe8d1lIJSVyYZCKPIRidObi61VitENoLUTSGsPeC0lsOmSZB1K2OfQ5ZrbHLq8n9ahxP2Yjy4XS4YSh/gqcY6fEphKAAAA/p/UJlqT/uIiAAAAAElFTkSuQmCC';

img.onload = function(){
  document.getElementById('imgData').innerHTML = "Widht: "+img.width+" Height:"+img.height;
};

img.src = base64Image;
```

```html
<div id='imgData'></div>
```